# find out locations of breaks (crossovers) from a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df = read.table(text="ID    location    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
M01 1   A   H   H   A   A   B
M02 2   A   H   A   A   A   B
M03 3   A   B   A   A   A   B
M04 4   H   B   H   A   A   B
M05 5   H   B   H   A   A   B
M06 6   A   B   H   A   A   H
M07 7   A   B   H   B   A   H
M08 8   A   B   H   A   A   H
M09 9   A   B   H   A   A   H
M10 10  B   B   H   A   A   H
M11 11  A   B   H   A   A   H
M12 12  A   B   H   A   A   H
M13 13  A   B   H   A   A   H
M14 14  B   B   B   A   A   H
M15 15  B   B   B   A   A   A", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to find the locations of crossovers or breaks (the junctions between different letters for each column). for example, for column `C1` the first junction should be row 3 and row 4. From row 1 to row 3, they are all `A`. row 4 is `H`. So the location of this crossover is 3. The expected result is a list of columns from `C1` to `C6`.

```
$C1             
3   5   9   10  13
$C2             
2               
$C3             
1   3   13      
$C4             
6   7           
$C5             

$C6             
5   14
```

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop over the 'C' columns with `lapply` and compare the adjacent elements to find the index

```
lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) which(x[-1]!= x[-length(x)]))
#$C1
#[1]  3  5  9 10 13

#$C2
#[1] 2

#$C3
#[1]  1  3 13

#$C4
#[1] 6 7

#$C5
#integer(0)

#$C6
#[1]  5 14
```

---

Or we can apply the `run-length-encoding` function i.e. `rle`, extract the `lengths`, get the cumulative sum and remove the last element.

```
lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) head(cumsum(rle(x)$lengths),-1))
```

Comment: I am surprised by your simple approach, compared to the function `locateXO` in `qtl` R package.

Comment: @akrun: why there is warning with  lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) which(x[-1]!= x)) ?

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli  Using the OP's data, I am not getting any warnings in R 3.3.0

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli  I noticed that you are not using the same code as I posted `which(x[-1]!= x[-length(x)])`  In your code, you are comparing two vectors of unequal length whereas I removed the first and last values in 'x' to make it equal length before comparing.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli  DId that fix your problem?

Comment: @akrun thanks for the explanation. thats why im gettting this warning longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.