# how to find 2 consecutive numbers from a list and display in a plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame:

```
df0 = read.table(text="ID   group   location    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
M01 1   1   A   H   H   A   A   B
M02 1   2   A   H   A   A   A   B
M03 1   3   A   B   A   A   A   B
M04 1   4   H   B   H   A   A   B
M05 1   5   H   B   H   A   A   B
M06 1   6   A   B   H   A   A   H
M07 1   7   A   B   H   B   A   H
M08 1   8   A   B   H   A   A   H
M09 1   9   A   B   H   A   A   H
M10 1   10  B   B   H   A   A   H
M11 1   11  A   B   H   A   A   H
M12 1   12  A   B   H   A   A   H
M13 1   13  A   B   H   A   A   H
M14 1   14  B   B   B   A   A   H
M15 1   15  B   B   B   A   A   A", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

using the code [to find out the crossovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042784/find-out-locations-of-breaks-crossovers-from-a-dataframe-in-r) , and then use "@rawr" 's code (see below) to get a list (which are the locations of my interest in the plot below).

```
d <- lapply(df0[-(1:3)], function(x) which(x[-1]!= x[-length(x)]))
idx <- lapply(d, function(x) c(FALSE, abs(diff(x)) == 1) | rev(c(FALSE, abs(diff(rev(x))) == 1)))
HI <- Filter(length, Map('[', d, idx))
```

I know how to create a plot without the plot symbol (pch=8).

The code I used to create the plot without the plot symbol (pch=8):

```
df1 <- reshape2::melt(df0, id.vars = c("group", "location", 
                                   "ID"), variable.name =   "individual_names", 
                  value.name = "text")
ggplot(df1, aes(x = ID, y = individual_names, fill = text)) + 
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_manual(name = "types", values = c(A = "#56B4E9", B = "#E69F00", H = "#009E73"), 
                              labels = c("A", "B", "H"))
```

I would like to create a plot with the plot symbol (pch=8) on the locations defined by the list `HI`. But I don't know how to pass `HI` list to ggplot (or other plot function) to create a plot looks like as below: Thank you for any helps.

[image]

Comment: you can get the first part with something like `idx <- lapply(d, function(x) c(FALSE, abs(diff(x)) == 1) | rev(c(FALSE, abs(diff(rev(x))) == 1))); Filter(length, Map('[', d, idx))` I'm not sure what you want in the second part

Comment: @rawr your code works for the first part. The second part is to plot the `df0` and show the result from your code on the plot by `scale_shape` or something else to distinguish with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mildly confused as to what you want exactly, partly because you deleted part of the explanation of the problem in your edit. But perhaps this is what you want?

#### Find the correct observations

I'm going to use `dplyr` here, mostly because `lag` is really convenient, and we want to keep working in a data.frame, since `ggplot` only takes those. Creating lists is just going to cause us pain.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(individual_names) %>% 
  mutate(change = text != lead(text)) %>% 
  filter(change & lag(change))
```

#### Create the plot

Now we simply pass `df2` to `geom_point` with the correct `pch` to make the plot:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = ID, y = individual_names, fill = text)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_point(data = df2, pch = 8, size = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "types", 
                    values = c(A = "#56B4E9", B = "#E69F00", H = "#009E73"), 
                    labels = c("A", "B", "H")) +
  coord_equal()
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: It would be perfect if it is possible to remove the `pch` from the legend same as  my example plot. Thanks.